# Invoke RichSinkFunction from RichMapFunction in Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have a sink which extends from **RichSinkFunction** that is caching some information.
When my process is finished, I want to update all that information that is cached so I want to force its invocation.

I can call that sink from an **KeyedProcessAccumulatorFunction**, calling it with the context of type **ReadOnlyContext** and it works.

```
public class PageAccumulateFunction implements KeyedProcessAccumulatorFunction{
    public SessionAccumulator accumulate(
            @NonNull Tuple2<CollectionMessage, PropertyInfo> value,
            @NonNull SessionAccumulator accumulator,
            @NonNull KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction.ReadOnlyContext ctx) {
        ....
        ctx.output(outputTag, message);
    }
}
```

But in my **RichMapFunction** class, I can't invoke that sink. I can get a **RuntimeContext** object (but not a ReadOnlyContext), but I don't know if I can use it to invoke the RichSinkFunction sink.

```
public class SessionMapper extends RichMapFunction<SessionAccumulator, GenericRecord>{
    public GenericRecord map(SessionAccumulator sessionAccumulator) {
        ....
        RuntimeContext ctx = getRuntimeContext();
        ....
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only process functions can use side outputs (which you write to via `ctx.output`).

A `MapFunction` automatically sends the return value of its `map` method downstream (toward the sink). It works this way because a map is a one-to-one mapping from inputs to outputs. Most other function types (e.g., process functions, flatmaps) are passed a Collector you can use to send events downstream.

Comment: Thank you, I solved it calling the sinks from an starter KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction. I had an onTimer and I could reuse an OnTimerContext to call the sinks on finish. I need to call another two sinks before this MapFunction, and this MapFunction is the starter output sink (output from the KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction)

Comment: Anyway I need to ensure, the sinks have finished before calling the MapFunction class, any idea.

Comment: That's not possible; the stages in your pipeline are decoupled, and earlier stages (like the map) can't have dependencies on later stages (like the sink). Also, you are not calling the sinks -- you are enqueueing data for them to process when they can get around to it.